# .BAT files: Launch the JVM in background

Tags: java, batch-file

Having read the post at [.bat files, nonblocking run/launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893203/bat-files-nonblocking-run-launch),

I still cannot achieve what I need: to have the .BAT file close once the start command is executed. My problem is that when the JVM starts the application launches a window so I end up with 2 windows being opened, when in fact one of them (the .BAT command) is just a startup process and doesn't do anything meaningful to the user.

I paste the .BAT code here:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem Starts the application

rem Check for Java Home and use that if available
if not "[%JAVA_HOME%]"=="[]" goto start_app
echo. JAVA_HOME not set. Application will not run!
goto end
:start_app
echo. Using java in %JAVA_HOME%
start "Application" "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe" -jar lib/pathToMyJarFile
goto end

:end
```

I'd like the .BAT process to terminate (or at least the window to close) once the JVM starts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try javaw.exe instead of java.exe.

Comment: Thanks! Using javaw solved the problem. (With or without the /b option to start)

Comment: I thought it was a problem with the bat file usage, but it looks like we need to use the console-less java launcher. From the SUN documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html): The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there is no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason

Comment: Continuing my original question...

I also thought of writing a native (C++) app to invoke the JVM programatically. My question is under what circumstances is this trully useful?

It seems not necesarry for the problem I described, which was solved much easier.

Many thanks,
Cristian

Answer (score 1):

Use `start /b`, see this:

- http://zeroflag.wordpress.com/2007/05/12/start-command/

Comment: This didn't do the trick, although the link you provided has very useful information. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing Christian. Just to confirm, you used this - `start "Application" /b "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe" -jar lib/pathToMyJarFile`, correct?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you thought - what I wrote will close the original command line window, but application windows will stay. What Gijs says is the way to go for what you want - glad you sorted it out!