# job control in windows so that control is passed to the program being opened

Tags: cmd

I am trying to open a program from the command line such that the control passes to that program but the control is passed back to the command prompt i.e., this happens - when I open progam1 from the command prompt, the program1 GUI starts but the control is passed back to the command prompt, i.e.,

```
C:\>program1
C:\>_
```

whereas, if I open another program2, the control is passed to program2, i.e. this happens

```
C:\>program2
```

and only after I close program2, the control is passed back to the command prompt, i.e., after closing program2,

```
C:\>program2
C:\>_
```

My question is I want program1 to behave like program2? Is there any way I can specify that when opening program1 from the command line?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.bat files, nonblocking run/launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893203/bat-files-nonblocking-run-launch)

Comment: `start /wait` could do the trick - or not. Depends on how the application is programmed.

Comment: I had success with `start program1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with `C:\>start program1`. It transferred control to `program1` which is different behavior from `C:\> program1`.